# Use Sharepoint list fields in JSON column formatting

Tags: list, column, json, json-formatting

Some data from other fields can't be reference when using JSON to format Sharepoint List columns. What is being done wrong?

**For Person fields**

```
"@currentField.title"         Works
"@currentField.email"         Works
"[$ThisField.title]"          Works
"[$ThisField.email]"          Works
"[$OtherField.title]"         Doesn't work
```

**For Text fields**

```
"[$OtherField]"               Works for some but not others
```

**For Number fields**

```
"[$OtherField]"               Doesn't work
```

**For Calculated fields**

```
"[$OtherField]"               Doesn't work
"[$OtherField.lookupvalue]"   Doesn't work
```

Here is my code, which I've labelled on the left with Yes/No on whether the reference to a variable actually works:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "8px"
      },
Y      "txtContent": "[$Owner.title]"
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Mail",
        "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
        "href": {
          "operator": "+",
          "operands": [
            "mailto:",
Y           "@currentField.email",
            "?subject=Task status&body=You are marked as owner of this task. Reminder prompt activated.\r\n---\r\n",
            "Raised by: ",
N           "[$OtherPersonField.title]",
            "\r\nOwner: ",
Y           "[$ThisPersonField.title]",
            " and Issue Detail %2D ",
Y           "[$ThisPersonField.email]",
            "\r\nPriority: ",
Y           "[$TextFieldA]",
            "\r\nContext: ",
N           "[$ACalculatedField]",
            " at ",
N           "[$TextFieldB]",
            "\r\nIssue: Checklist No. %2D ",
N           "[$NumberField]",
            " and Issue Detail %2D ",
N           "[$LongTextField]",
            "\r\nClick this link for more info. https://PATH.sharepoint.com/sites/SITE/Lists/LIST/VIEW.aspx?web=1%26useFiltersInViewXml=1%26FilterField1=ThisPersonField%26FilterValue1=",
Y           "@currentField.title",
            "%26FilterType1=User%26FilterOp1=In"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

All of the fields that I am trying to reference are shown in the current view.

Comment: What about fields with more than 1 word? I have played with about every format and none work.

Answer (score 1):

Go to List Settings > Click on the Column name 
[image]

goto URL there,  then get the last name after the last "=" Mark

[image]